Ingesting Cppcheck and Fortify findings into GitLab
I am looking for examples of parsing CppCheck and Fortify XML reports into the GitLab SAST report schema.
Specifically, I am looking to see how people populate the "Identifiers" array in the schema from the information contained in the reports, but I'm interested in how they're populating all fields.
